# Sencha cmd does not create packager.json file

Tags: sencha-touch, package

I'm creating my first app with Sencha, following the 'getting started' section on the documentation. I'm using Sencha cmd  v5.0.1.231, and Sencha Touch v2.4.0. When i run the command  'sencha -sdk /path/to/touch generate app MyApp .', the 'packager.json' file is missing. I'm on Mavericks.

```
[INF] Processing Build Descriptor : default
[INF] Loading app json manifest...
[INF] Concatenating output to file /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/myapp/build/temp/production/myapp/sencha-compiler/cmd-packages.js
[INF] writing content to /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/myapp/bootstrap.js
[INF] appending content to /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/myapp/bootstrap.js
[INF] appending content to /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/myapp/bootstrap.js
[INF] appending content to /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/myapp/bootstrap.js
[INF] Appending content to /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/myapp/bootstrap.json
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer on the Sencha docs.

> As of Sencha Cmd 5.0+, Cordova and PhoneGap are cohesive pieces of the Sencha frameworks. Every app generated with Sencha Cmd has the ability to switch on native building through these services. Sencha Cmd will take care of all the repetitive tasks, such as building your app, getting it in the proper place for Cordova or PhoneGap, and running the proper commands to build, emulate, or run your application.
>
> For more information on getting started with native development,
>   please see the Apache Cordova Platform Guides. These guides provide
>   getting started information and prerequisites needed to get your
>   system up and running.
>
> Important Notes
>
> **packager.json has been fully removed**. If your project still contains
>   this file, you may safely remove it. This file was only used by
>   Sencha’s legacy Native Packager.
>
> For Cordova and PhoneGap, Sencha Cmd
>   can only create DEBUG versions of applications, not a Release (for an
>   app store) version. To create release versions, you must use a
>   packager, such as Eclipse or IntelliJ for Android, and Xcode for iOS.